# Showing that minimal polynomial divides $(x^4+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $A^8=I$ but $A^4\ne I$.

Then I know $m_A(x) \mid x^8-1$, but $m_A(x)\nmid x^4-1$, where $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial.

Now, I want to say that since $x^8-1=(x^4+1)(x^4-1)$, it follows that $m_A(x)\mid x^4+1$. This seems obvious, but in order to justify this, don't I need to know that the ideal $(m_A(x))$ is prime/maximal? Otherwise, what argument could I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't conclude that $m_A(x)$ divides $x^4+1$. For example, if $A$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $x^8-1$, then $A^8=I$ and $A^4\neq I$, and $m_A(x)=x^8-1$, so in particular $m_A(x)$ does not divide $x^4+1$.

Comment: But we know $(x^4-1)$ is coprime with $(x^4+1)$ since we're in a UFD. Are you sure this wouldn't imply what I want?

Comment: I don't see how $x^4-1$ and $x^4+1$ being coprime helps you. And yes I'm sure, since I gave an example where the minimal polynomial fails to divide $x^4+1$.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that $x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$, and that $m_A(A)=0$, but matrix multiplication doesn't work the way ordinary multiplication does. Specifically, it's very possible for both $B=A^4-1$ and $C=A^4+1$ to be non-zero, while their product $BC=A^8-1$ *is* the zero matrix.

For another, perhaps more extreme, example, consider the $n\times n$ matrix with $1$'s in the entries just above the main diagonal and all other entries being $0$'s. This matrix has the minimal polynomial $x^n$.